# Need to compare two columns and complete a third with data from one the sheets

Tags: excel

I have to compare two columns from two sheets with some data. If the columns have the same data, i have to display the data of one the sheets (a third column).

I tried with a

> If, Vlookup and Index

formula but its not working, at least for me.

On Sheet 1 i have the "G" Column (original data) and on Sheet 2 i have the "C" column. If both cells match, i need the data from the "A" column on Sheet 2 to be displayed.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH and IFERROR.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(G1==SHEET2!C1, SHEET2!A1, "Cells do not match")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the result on *Sheet 1*, on *Sheet 1* use formula like this:

```
=INDEX(SHEET2!A:A,MATCH(G1,SHEET2!C:C,0))
```

I recommend you to limit the ranges (`A:A` and `C:C`) to match actual data tables to increase performance.